# Unable to locate file in docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker and creating a simple test app to test my docker container, but docker unable to locate the `server.py` file.

The directory structure of my project is:

```
<project>
|
|-- Dockerfile
|-- app
      |
      |-- requirements.txt
      |-- server.py
```

Below is the `Dockerfile` content:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER name <mail@domain.com>

COPY . /app  # do I need this ?
COPY ./app/requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN apt-get -y update && \
apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod +x server.py    # ERROR: No such file or directory

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["server.py"]    # ERROR: No such file or directory
```

I'm using boot2docker on windows.

What am I missing here?

Comment: maybe you copy app to /app/app?

Comment: Could you check if  `COPY . /app` isn't creating `/app/app/server.py` in your running container? That could explain why you can't find it. As you're copying everything in `.` to `/app`. And in . there is already a folder called `/app` -> `app/app` in docker container.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're copying your local `/app/` folder to the `/app/` folder in the running Docker container (as mentioned in the comments) creating `/app/app/server.py` in the Docker container.

### How to resolve

A simple fix will be to change

```
COPY . /app
```

to

```
COPY ./app/server.py /app/server.py
```

### Explanation

The command `COPY` works as follows:

```
COPY <LOCAL_FROM> <DOCKER_TO>
```

You're selecting everything in the folder where the Dockerfile resides, by using `.` in your first `COPY`, thereby selecting the local `/app` folder to be added to the Docker's folder. The destination you're allocating for it in the Docker container is also `/app` and thus the path in the running container becomes `/app/app/..` explaining why you can't find the file.

Have a look at the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).