# How do I access a flat file using Airflow

Tags: python, sqlite, airflow

I am creating a simple DAG with one PythonOperator. It has an error when trying to open the file 'sample.csv'
(ERROR: No such file or directory: 'sample.csv')

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator   import PythonOperator
import datetime
import airflow
import csv, sqlite3, smtplib,os

default_args = {
    "depends_on_past" : False,
    "start_date"      : airflow.utils.dates.days_ago( 1 ),
    "retries"         : 1,
    "retry_delay"     : datetime.timedelta( hours= 5 ),
    "email"           : "email@gmail.com",
    "max_active_runs" : 2,
    "concurrency"     : 2,
}

def python_callable_new():
    print("Attempting sqlite connection 3...")
    con = sqlite3.connect('test.db') 
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOCATIONS (city TEXT, state TEXT, country TEXT, postcode TEXT);")
    
    # ERROR occurs here when trying to open the csv file
    with open('sample.csv',encoding='utf8') as fin: 
        dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
        to_db = [(i['city'], i['state'], i['country'], i['postcode']) for i in dr]

    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO LOCATIONS (city, state, country, postcode) VALUES (?,?,?,?);", to_db)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    return 'End of callable. '

with airflow.DAG( "file_sensor_test_v1", default_args= default_args, schedule_interval= "*/5 * * * *", ) as dag:


    do_python_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'do-py-operation',
        python_callable= python_callable_new,
    )
```

To start the airflow environment, I run the following docker command

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v C:\Users\chris\VisualStudioCodeWorkspace\airflow\dag:/usr/local/airflow/dags  puckel/docker-airflow webserver
```

Basically, I just want to access the contents of a csv file within my python callable. How should I go about doing this, as my current method is not working.

Comment: Is your sample.csv located on the same folder as your dag py file?

Comment: @Elad yes, I have tried it inside the /dag folder (same as where my dag is located)

Comment: use command line to list files in that folder and make sure it's `sample.csv` and not `sample.csv.csv`

Comment: I just double checked and its there as 'sample.csv'. What I'm confused on, is that when I did this within python, I just had to place the file within the python folder like so '/python/sample.csv'

Comment: probably you are not copying the whole folder when setting up the docker. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126926/unable-to-locate-file-in-docker-container